# TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo metrics

Tags: tensorflow

I know it's a banality, but i'm really confused on what Speed (ms) and COCO mAP means [HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).

I get the idea, lower speed and higher mAP are better, but can i ask what does those metrics mean?
I have to write a report about a project that uses one of the model listed in the github model of tensorflow, so i would like a technical description of those two if possible. About COCO mAP i found something already, i'm trying to understand it, but nothing related to Speed. What does speed measure?

I'm sorry about the stupid question, but i like to fully understand things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to inference speed, how much time it take for the network to provide an output based on your input.